# Grep from wget without saving files

Tags: grep, wget

I am trying to download a site (with permission) and grepping a particular text from that. The problem is I want to grep on the go without saving any files on local drive. Following command does not help.

```
wget --mirror site.com -O - | grep TEXT
```

Comment: What do you mean by `does not help`?

Answer (score 0):

wget command manual (man page) tells, the usage of the command should be:

```
wget [option]... [URL]...
```

in your case, it should be:

```
wget --mirror -O - site.com|grep TXT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl:

`curl -s http://www.site.com | grep TEXT`

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
wget -qO- site.com |grep TEXT
```

and

```
curl -vs site.com 2>&1 |grep TEXT
```

Comment: It just stops on the first page. It does not crawl the website.